# Bundle .NET 3.5 libs with app, so it runs on machines with only .NET 2.0 installed?

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, installation, .net-2.0, software-distribution

I want to use LINQ on machines with only .NET Framework 2.0 installed.

I've alread read about LINQBridge. But can't I simply set "***copy local***" to the referenced assemblies like `System.Core.dll` and `System.Xml.Linq.dll` to get the functionality I need?

Are there any drawbacks? Is this even allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net 3.5 is really just .Net 2.0 with some extra dlls.  There is no 3.5 runtime.  If you include the dlls you need, the application will run without any problems.

From the following article concerning the linq bridge comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx

> First, it's important to understand
> that C# 3.0 and Framework 3.5 are
> designed to work with CLR 2.0—the same
> CLR version that Framework 2.0 uses.
> This means that the C# 3.0 compiler
> emits IL code that runs on the same
> virtual machine as before.
>
> This makes Framework 3.5 additive—just
> as Framework 3.0 was
> additive—comprising additional
> assemblies that enhance the existing
> 2.0 Framework and CLR. So there's nothing to stop us from writing our
> own assemblies that do the work of
> Framework 3.5 (at least, the critical
> bits required for local LINQ queries).
>
> The compiler then looks for Where,
> OrderBy and Select methods. The
> critical thing is that it can find
> appropriately named methods with the
> correct signatures (typically
> extension methods). But it doesn't
> matter what assembly the methods come
> from. LINQBridge simply provides
> another source of these methods—that
> are functionally identically to those
> implemented in the Framework 3.5
> assemblies.

Comment: linq bridge provides methods which are in the 2.0 framework.  I'll append my answer to show.

Comment: You mean 3.5. Framework, otherwise your comment doesn't make sense. What is the point of reinventing these extension methods? I have to redistribute either System.Core.dll or LINQBridge.dll anyway..

Comment: because that way you don't have to add all the dlls to the installation, only that one.  it'll act as a shim between the framework and your code, so you don't run into a scenario where you expect a dll to be installed on the machine and it's not. If you include all the dlls into setup project that you know you need, then there is no point to using it.  It just saves you the hassle.